# Travel to USA from Pakistan with passport about to expire

Tags: usa, passports

Can I travel to USA from Pakistan on a Pakistani passport from June 26 to July 17,2018 with Passport expiry date of September 17,2018 with a valid US visa. Hope I will be able to board the Qatar airline?

Comment: Have you checked the airline’s website?

Comment: You have so much time. Why don’t you renew your passport before your travel?

Comment: I just did some research and it looks like renewal of a Pakistani passport takes 10 days for a normal renewal and 4 days for an urgent renewal and costs less than $50. I would never risk getting stuck in some emergency when abroad and being with an expired passport and thinking *man i had 3 months and it would have taken only 3 days to renew it*. I suggest you should renew it even if it is fine to travel on that passport near its expiry dates

Comment: As noted in ohter comments, it will likely work. However keep in mind you are coming from Pakistan. I can see having a soon to expire Pakistani passport may raise a flag at US immigration. I would do everything you could to get it renewed before you fly to help avoid any unnecessary headaches.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  The rule is that a traveler's passport must be valid for six months beyond the intended period of stay unless the country issuing the passport is in the so-called "six-month club."  Pakistan is in the six-month club.

A link to the current list may be found on [the Customs and Border Protection website](https://www.cbp.gov/document/bulletins/six-month-club-update).

For those with passports issued by a country on the list, the passport need only be valid until the traveler's date of departure.  In your case, you have two extra months.

If the "admit until" date would normally be after September 17, however, you should expect that it will be September 17 instead.  For example, if you're arriving as a B-2 visitor on June 26, you would normally be admitted until December 25 or so, but with a passport expiring on September 17, the stamp will probably say September 17.

As mentioned in a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114295/travel-to-usa-from-pakistan/114301#comment278645_114295), you can also get a new passport.  Your visa will remain valid, and you can use the valid visa in your old passport along with your new passport.